# how can i create true loop?

Tags: javascript, css

```
        var resimler = Array('uludağ.jpg', 'yesilturbe.jpg', 'taksi.jpg');
        var sayi = resimler.length - 1;
        var now = 0;
        function slideback()
        {
            $('body').css('background-image','url(' + resimler[now] + ')');
            now = now + 1;
            if(now==sayi)
            {
                now = 0;
            }
        }

        while(true){
            $(function() {
                    setTimeout(slideback, 2200);
            });
        }
```

My Javascript codes above, css codes below..

```
body{
                background-image:url('taksi.jpg');
                background-size:100%; 
                background-attachment:fixed;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                src='taksi.jpg',
                sizingMethod='scale')";
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                src='taksi.jpg',
                sizingMethod='scale');
            }
```

I want to change background-image every 2200 miliseconds. As you can see I have 3 image, and I want to create infinite loop

> while(true){}

but my firefox fall down. How can i create true loop for my purpose?

Comment: `setInterval` will be a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while(true)` will send your browser into a horrible infinite loop and lock it up. Don't do that.

Look at the Javascript `setInterval` method (eg. `setInterval(slideback, 2200)`) to repeat the method every 2200 milliseconds.

Comment: can you here: cekirhegizmettaksi.com it can't turn to third image? why?

Comment: @user1870012: Because you are setting `now` to `0` when it is `2`, i.e. you are only toggling between `0` and `1`. You only want to reset `now` when it has an index larger than the highest index in the array.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop. The "most direct" translation of your code would be to call `setTimeout(slideback, 2200)` at the end of your `slideback` method. That's pretty much saying "and do the same thing again in about 2 seconds).

Even better would be to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
setInterval(slideback, 2200);
```

Remember, that the JS- and HTML-interaction is pretty much event based. This means that you almost never want an infinite loop directly in your code (that's true for *most* modern development environments).

Comment: Or use a setInterval function

Comment: You will need `setInterval()` for an "infinite" loop... ;)

Comment: Well, that shows how little I actually know about JS ;-) I updated my answer.